# Advantages to using FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING with memory mapped files?

Tags: windows, memory-mapped-files, createfile

Are there any advantages to using a memory mapped file that has been created with the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING flag? In my situation, reads into the memory mapped file are random access. Writes are most often appends with new data, and less often random access when corrections/updates are made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just citing MSDN:

> FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING
>   The file or device is being opened with no system caching for data reads and writes. 
>   **This flag does not affect hard disk caching or memory mapped files**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

So, there are no advantages. It would just make your code more complex if you tried to handle all the alignment needs of the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING.